# Absolute Positioning Miss Formatting on resized document

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with my positioning. All of the items in my website are absolute positioned. They look completely fine when my web-brower is at it's full size, but when I shorten the (safari) browser then some items in my website move over others. At first I thought the problem was that absolute positioning does that automatically, but when I looked into it further I found some of my items that were in absolute positioning stayed at the same place even when my web page got smaller.  It looks extremely bad and i would really appreciate help with my problem.  How do I get things on my website to stay in the same place even when the web-browser shrinks.

```
#imagerotator
{
position:absolute;
right:118px;
top:65px;
}
```

Comment: Absolute positioning can be tricky this way. Can you clarify why ALL of the items are positioned this way? Usually you don't need to position EVERYTHING absolute.

Comment: I recommend changing those pixels to percents, that way, no matter what size the page may be, it will always be absolute of a percent of that particular window size.

Comment: Well not ALL of the items are positioned in absolute. What I meant to say was MOST of the items are absolute positioned and some items that are positioned move and others that are absolute positioned don't move. @jampafoo

Comment: Well without seeing your site and all the css, it is going to be difficult to tell you the issues. What I would say is to check that if you have absolute positioned items that are not acting like you want them to, sometimes you have to contain them within relatively positioned containers. This may not be the solution, but again, need to see more of your code.

Comment: I'm not very experienced with web-design and am most familiar with using pixels not percentages. Could you explain to me how to convert it to a percentage and have it be in the same place  @Brendan